# Audit log in Cassandra 2.2.8 community edition

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.2

Is there any way to log queries along with user that executed the query in Cassandra community edition?

I'm looking for a Server level solution, not driver/client based solution

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try nodetool settraceprobability**

```
nodetool settraceprobability <value>
```

> Sets the probability for tracing a request.

- Value is a probability between 0 and 1.

> Tracing a request usually requires at least 10 rows to be inserted.
>   A probability of 1.0 will trace everything whereas lesser amounts (for example, 0.10) only sample a certain percentage of statements.
>
> The trace information is stored in a system_traces keyspace that holds two tables – sessions and events, which can be easily queried to answer questions, such as what the most time-consuming query has been since a trace was started. Query the parameters map and thread column in the system_traces.sessions and events tables for probabilistic tracing information.

Note : *Care should be taken on large and active systems, as system-wide tracing will have a performance impact. Unless you are under very light load, tracing all requests (probability 1.0) will probably overwhelm your system*

If you don't want to use this, then you have log the query from the client side [How to use Query Logger ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684084/2320144). There is no other way

Source : https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsSetTraceProbability.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Ashraful.
I can't find the query and the user who executed it neither on system_traces.sessions nor in system_traces.events, so I don't think this is a good solution for getting audit info I need.

Comment: What value did you set ?

Comment: I tried with 1 because I need every query to be logged

Comment: If you don't want to use this, then you have log the query from the client side https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684084/2320144. There is no other way