# How to get query string in case CQLStatement,QueryState and QueryOptions is given

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

Cassandra has org.apache.cassandra.cql3.QueryHandler interface which provide apis to handle external queries from client.

Below api which handles prepared statment:

```
public ResultMessage processPrepared(CQLStatement statement, QueryState state, QueryOptions options) throws RequestExecutionException, RequestValidationException;
```

I want to log queryString and value passed to it,  in case CQLStatement,QueryState and QueryOptions is given . How can i get it?

I Believe a person who has worked on cassandra code can help me out in this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684084/2320144

Comment: Hi, QueryLogger can help while writing client side code ..I am planning to put some logger at cassadra server side..so i believe this wont help here

Comment: I don't think you can get query string from CQLStatement, But you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46622652/2320144

Comment: Query string is converted into Statement there is no way to get back the query string. I have check cassandra code, they log the query string in trace level i.e `Tracing.trace("Parsing {}", queryStr);`

Comment: It seems you are right. I have spent lots of time to some how get back the query from the statement but could not get successful yet.

Answer (score 1):

This would be very difficult in 2.1. With newer versions where for logging they needed this they just recreate it as well as possible. You can see how in the [ReadCommand](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/684e250ba6e5b5bd1c246ceac332a91b2dc90859/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/ReadCommand.java#L588) implementations, theres a `name()` or `toCQLString()` used in things like slow query logging. You could backport this and the 2 implementations of `appendCQLWhereClause` for ability to do similar and then build one for modification statement.

in `getPrepared()` you can get the `rawCQLStatement` from the ParsedStatement.Prepared and stash it in the thread local.

You may want to alternatively consider using a custom implementation of tracing ([example](https://github.com/thelastpickle/cassandra-zipkin-tracing)) or using triggers and building a mutation logger.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will post my final answer once i am done.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- create a class that would implement the `QueryHandler` interface and make Cassandra aware of it
- in that class you can maintain a list of the queries (add to this list when `prepare` method is being called) and the current query that you will get from the list when `getPrepared` it's called; you can get it from the list using the `MD5Digest id`
- when `processPrepared` is called you can replace the `?` in the query string with the values in the `QueryOptions options.getValues()`.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Per has shared your pull with me :) ..It is helpful..I am working on it will share my changes as well