# Log queries executed by Spring Data Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

We are using `AbstractCassandraConfiguration` to configure `cassandra entities`, is there a way to log queries executed by the application using `application.properties`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are multiple approaches:

1. If you use Spring Data for Apache Cassandra version 2.0 or higher, then you can use your logging configuration to activate CQL logging. Set the log level of `org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate` to `DEBUG`.
2. In any other case (or instead of 1.), use `QueryLogger` that is directly attached to your `Cluster` object. See [What is a good way to discover all queries made by a Cassandra java app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683371/what-is-a-good-way-to-discover-all-queries-made-by-a-cassandra-java-app/40684084#40684084) for further details.

Comment: In case 1, the logger logs `DEBUG CqlTemplate - Executing CQL Statement [com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement@50187558]` which is not really relevant since the toString on DefaultSimpleStatement is not implemented as expected..

Comment: Fixed after version 3.0.5

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to achieve this

***1) Setting the cassandra logging level to DEBUG***

***logging.level.org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate=DEBUG***

By enabling the debug logs you can see the queries , but you may see the java objects instead of actual queries . For that you can use logback , logback has conversionRule  to convert the log line  and log them as we want . So we will use conversionRule to convert the java object to queries

First thing is to setup few loggers and appenders by creating logback.xml

```xml
<configuration>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="cql" converterClass="com.converter.CqlQueryExtractor" />

    <appender name="CONSOLE_CQL" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" >
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                 %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %cql%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" >
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %X{Nonce} - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <logger name="org.springframework.data.cassandra" additivity="false" level="DEBUG" >
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE_CQL" />
    </logger>

    <root level="INFO" >
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Now create converter the we referred in xml file

```java
public class CqlQueryExtractor extends ClassicConverter {


    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
        Object[] args = iLoggingEvent.getArgumentArray();
        for(Object arg : args){
            if(arg instanceof SimpleStatement){
                return ((SimpleStatement)arg).getQuery();
            }
        }
        return iLoggingEvent.toString();

    }
}
```

***2) Using QueryLogger***

The **`QueryLogger`** provides clients with the ability to log queries executed by the driver, and especially, it allows client to track slow queries, i.e. queries that take longer to complete than a configured threshold in milliseconds.

```java
Cluster cluster = ...
QueryLogger queryLogger = QueryLogger.builder(cluster)
    .withConstantThreshold(...)
    .withMaxQueryStringLength(...)
.build();
cluster.register(queryLogger);
```

Follow the official Docs for more [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/manual/logging/#logging-query-latencies)